# Reading concrete class property within a generic method that doesn't get generic type instance

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have a generic method that is made generic just for the purpose of returning correct type so upstream callers don't have to cast returned values.

```
public T Add<T>(string name, string details, ...)
    where T: BaseClass
{
    // somehow get correct ObjectType
    ObjectType type = ??????;
    T result = Repo.Add<T>(type, name, details, ...);
    ...
    return result;
}
```

### Problem

The problem of this generic method is that I'm not getting an instance of a concrete class represented with generic type. This means that callers of this method have to explicitly provide generic type as type inference can't be done.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract ObjectType ActualType { get; }

    ...
}
```

Implemented child classes define this property as a quasy constant

```
public class ConcreteClass: BaseClass
{
    public override ObjectType ActualType
    {
        get { return ObjectType.SomeType; }
    }

    ...
}
```

### Question

Based on generic method call

```
var result = Add<ConcreteClass>("title", "details");
```

how can I get the value of `ActualType` within my `Add<T>` method? I also tried adding `new()` generic type constraint, but that doesn't compile as my `BaseClass` is abstract, so I'm unable to call

```
new T();
```

within my method to get that `ActualType` value.

Comment: How about adding the `new()` constraint to the `Add` method?

Comment: @DavidG: I could change my method to take concrete class instance but then it would be against common convention used by classes in the same assembly. They all take simple typed parameters and return application model entity as callers aren't required to create incomplete entities missing data (i.e. `Id`, `CreatedOn` etc.) just to create actual instances based on database...

Comment: sorry, I removed that comment, but the replacement about the new constraint stands.

Comment: @DavidG: As written in my question I can't use `new()` generic type constraint as my `BaseClass` is `abstract`. Compiler won't compile as **abstract** `BaseClass` can't be instantiated.

Comment: That is odd because it compiles for me. Are you on the latest version of VS/c#?

Comment: @DavidG: I'm using VS2013. That's odd on your side. As [documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) *To use the new constraint, the type **cannot be abstract**.*

Comment: I'm just running it in LinqPad, I can send you the code (or go into chat?)

Comment: Also I think the docs mean that the type passed in cannot be abstract, not that the type constraint is abstract.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik new() constraint works with abstracts.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was jumping conclusions to quickly. I had a higher generic caller using the same constraint but missing the `new()` one. I automatically thought that my added constraint was the culprit but wasn't. It was higher up, where I needed to add another constraint. **Stupid me**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the `new()` constraint to your `Add` method like this:

```
public T Add<T>(string name, string details)
    where T: BaseClass, new()
{
    T result = new T();
    //snip  
    return result;
}

public abstract class BaseClass { /* snip */ }

public class ConcreteClass: BaseClass { /* snip */ }
```

Which means this code will work:

```
var thing = Add<ConcreteClass>("Fred", "Lives in France");
```

According to the MSDN documentation on the [new constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx):

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class
>   declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. **To use the
>   new constraint, the type cannot be abstract**.

This refers to the type passed in, not the other constraint on your method.

Comment: I was jumping conclusions to quickly. I had a higher generic caller using the same constraint but missing the `new()` one. I automatically thought that my added constraint on the lower generic method was the culprit but wasn't. It was higher up, where I needed to add the same constraint. **Stupid me**.

Comment: I created a [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y3W7kb) that shows it works with abstract and `new()` constraint.

Comment: Well like Carl Sagan said: *There are naive questions, tedious questions, ill-phrased questions, questions put after inadequate self-criticism. But every question is a cry to understand the world. There is no such thing as a dumb question*

Comment: But regarding my original question *Reading a property of a concrete class within a generic method*. Is making a instance of my generic class the only way of reading that particular property? Is there any other way? Uhmm... Statics maybe? But that doesn't allow abstract modifier, so my base class would already predefine `ActualType` which would be invalid... Any other way maybe?

Comment: I think you answered your own question there. Reading a property of a concrete class surely needs an instance. As for statics, pretty sure you can't override a static so may not work for you.